# Solving MX=N where M is structured as a Gaussian 4th-moment tensor

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-solver, matrix-equations

I'm looking to solve numerically the following equation for $(d,d)$ variable $X$, in Einstein summation notation

$$M_{ijkl}X_{kl}=N_{ij}$$

Where $M$ is a $(d,d,d,d)$ 4th-moment tensor of random variable $(a,b)$ and admits representation in terms of 2nd and 1st moment tensors based on the [Isserlis theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isserlis%27_theorem)

$$M_{ijkl}=E[a_i a_j b_k b_k]=AA_{ij}BB_{kl}+AB_{ik}AB_{jl}+AB_{il}AB_{jk}-2A_iA_jB_kB_l$$

relying on shorthand $AA=E[aa'],BB=E[bb'],AB=E[ab'],A=E[a],B=E[b]$

If my factorization only had the first term, an explicit solution is formed by inverting $AA$ and $BB$ matrices

$$X=(BB)^{-1}N(AA)^{-1}$$

However, the presence of $AB$ terms is complicating things, probably an iterative method is required. Is there a standard procedure for this kind of structured linear equation system? Any literature pointers appreciated!

Comment: If $d$ is not too large, you can represent $M$ by a $d^2 \times d^2$ matrix and arrange $X$ and $N$ into $d^2 \times 1$ matrices.  Some care is needed to make sure all terms have been accounted for.

Comment: Yes, if $d$ was not too large, I could ignore the structure and treat it as a regular linear problem

Answer (score 3):

I encountered a similar problem in the past and I could find no simple solution either. One of the terms is a Kronecker product, another is a rank-1 modification, but the rest makes the problem more difficult. I don't think there is a closed-form solution; you could try using an iterative method, dropping some terms to get a preconditioner.

But if someone has a better solution, I am all ears!

Comment: I've played around with Jacobi algorithm to invert it, and it diverges when AB correlations are large